# BaseAdapter extending questions

Tags: android

I need to add a checkbox to this listview, I have the row.xml setup with a textview/chrono/checkbox.  Do I have to show the checkbox in my baseadapter extending?  Also why does that getSystemService() error out on me?

```
package com.walkarchdev.tasktracker;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TTAdapterView extends BaseAdapter {

public View v;

public TTAdapterView(Context context){
    super();

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    this.v = convertView;

    if(v==null){
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    }
    TextView task = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Chronometer time = (Chronometer)v.findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);
    //Checkbox complete = (Checkbox)v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

    return v;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why does that getSystemService()
>   error out on me?

`getSystemService()` is a method on `Context`. Save the context passed as an argument in the constructor and use it to call the `getSystemService()` method

```
Do I have to show the checkbox in my baseadapter extending?
```

If you intend to use the states of checkbox then you must store it in a variable in order to monitor the checked states

Comment: final TTAdapterView aa = new TTAdapterView(this);
       // aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 0);
        myListView.setAdapter(aa);
        
        
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
         public void onClick(View v){
          aa.add(myEditText.getText().toString());
          //taskitems.add(count, myEditText.getText().toString());
          aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
          myEditText.setText("");
          myEditText.requestFocus();
                             }
        });

Comment: I can't do the add to my adapter like I could with an arrayadapter.  What is the way to do this with the baseadapter?

Comment: you can't do the add so simply for BaseAdapter. What I see from the snippet you posted is that you return 0 from the getCount method. Instead you should return the size of the list, because the getcount method is called internally by the adapter which in turn decides when to calls the getView method. For more details see this link http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=327. and this http://www.androidguys.com/2008/07/14/fancy-listviews-part-one/

Answer (score 0):

Without manually working with checkbox state in your adapter you will have the problem with checkboxes states in your ListView when scroll it down.

What kind of error do you have calling `getSystemService`?

Comment: The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type TTAdapterView

Comment: Yep, you should call it through context instance. I do it in adapter's constructor and pass context as parameter